# Get-PnPFile which allow to create the folder path if the folder path does not exists

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp-powershell, pnp

I have this command to get a sharepoint file and save it to local folder;-

```
$file = Get-PnPFile -Url $Attachment.ServerRelativeUrl -FileName $AttachmentFileName -Path $Attachmentpath -AsFile -Force
```

but this script will not work if the folder path does not exists. so how i can force this command to create the folder if the folder does not exists ?

Thanks

Comment: Get-PnPFile cmdlet will not create a local folder automatically. You have to make sure if folder is available before this command and pass valid folder URL to command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the New-Item cmdlet to create the folder if it does not already exist. Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
$folderPath = "C:\Temp\Attachments"
if (!(Test-Path $folderPath)) {
  New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $folderPath
}
$file = Get-PnPFile -Url $Attachment.ServerRelativeUrl -FileName $AttachmentFileName -Path $folderPath -AsFile -Force
```